# RSpec / Capybara tests don't pass after assets precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I have a problem with testing my app using RSpec and Capybara. Tests were passing till I didn't use `rails assets:precompile`.

One of the problems is Capybara function `click_button "Button"` called on submit button. When is used one time nothing happens. Problem is solved when I using it twice:

```
click_button "Button"
click_button "Button"
```

In this case, tests passing again. I have no idea what `rails assets:precompile` spoiled.

Answer (score 1):

Running `rails assets:precompile` can sometimes lead to a state where Rails no longer detects changes in the assets and won't dynamically recompile them in the test environment. You can usually fix that by running `rails assets:clobber`.

As for needing to click the button twice, that usually means you're attempting to click before some needed JS has fully loaded. You can verify that by sleeping for a few seconds and then clicking the button.

```
sleep 5
click_button "Button"
```

To fix that correctly you need to check for something on the page that isn't visible until the page is ready to be used.

```
expect(page).to have_css('some_selector.ready`) # verify element, class name on element, etc that isn't there until page is ready
click_button "Button"
```

Comment: Unfortunately is still the same. I tried `sleep 5` and even `sleep 10`. When I tried to use `sleep 30` before button click and I took control and clicked it manually everything works correctly. Everything looks correct. I don't know why Capibara has a problem with click this button.

Comment: @Damian If sleeping doesn't fix it then it's likely something to do with the button and location of the click (or you haven't clobbered the assets and are using old broken ones)-- is it a standard button or does it have JS behavior attached to it? Does it have other elements overlapping it? What driver are you using with Capybara?  Did you try clobbering the assets?  When you say "took control", what exactly do you mean (i.e. did you just move the mouse and click the button, or did you resize the window, click somewhere else for focus, then click the button, etc)

Comment: This button doesn't have attached JS. I using 'selenium-webdriver'. Yes, I tried `rails assets:clobber`. "Took control" I meant I click button manually when browser window with test appeared. Generally, everything looks correct in this view.

Comment: @Damian Then you're going to need to provide the versions of everything you're using, the actual HTML around/including the button,  surrounding test code, and possibly a screenshot for anyone to be able to diagnose your issue. - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask